# How to display a string in case a condition with zero value occurs for an output variable of type VARCHAR in a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server

I have to output a few fields through a temp table that I have already created `#SweepActivityTransactions`

```
INSERT INTO #SweepActivityTransactions (Difference)
   SELECT TOP 100
      CASE
         WHEN (CAT.RequestedAmount - CAT.ConfirmedAmount) = 0
           THEN @DIFFERENCEDECIMAL
           ELSE (CAT.RequestedAmount - CAT.ConfirmedAmount) 
      END AS 'Difference'
   FROM 
      CustomerAccount_Transaction CAT WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE 
      EntryDate = @BusinessDate 
      AND CAT.TransactionExceptionType_FK = 0
END
```

According to the condition above,I have to display a hyphen (-_ on the screen in case the difference comes out to be zero else the value of the difference.

Since the field difference is of type `varchar(18,2)`, I cannot display the hyphen directly(since it is a `varchar` type).

I thought of  using this

```
SET @DIFFERENCEVARCHAR = '-'
SET @DIFFERENCEDECIMAL = (SELECT CAST(@DIFFERENCEVARCHAR AS decimal(18,2)) )
```

But even this is not working.Could anyone suggest a way to display - on the screen in case `CAT.RequestedAmount - CAT.ConfirmedAmount` is zero else the exact value.

UPDATES - Sample Data -

IF ((CAT.RequestedAmount - CAT.ConfirmedAmount) = 0, display -
else display the difference

```
    SCREEN 
    Difference
        -
      $3.45
      $6.77
        -
        -
      $2.33
```

Comment: There is no `varchar(18,2)` datatype in SQL Server - `varchar` only has a **length** (like `Varchar(18)`) - but not also a "precision" like for `decimal(18,2)`

Comment: I'm thinking that's a type, and the OP meant `decimal(18,2)`.  However, the question is still very unclear.  Sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: You can't cast '-' as a decimal, but you can cast a decimal as a varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to output a varchar:

```
 CASE
     WHEN (CAT.RequestedAmount - CAT.ConfirmedAmount) = 0
       THEN @DIFFERENCEVARCHAR
       ELSE '$'+CAST((CAT.RequestedAmount - CAT.ConfirmedAmount) AS varchar(31))
  END AS 'Difference'
```

Comment: but the output in normal scenario needs to be in this format $2.55 in case the value > 0 else - .the varchar will not be formatted with the $ sign

Comment: It can't be done.  '-' cannot be output as a numeric value.  And you can't have an output column that is "decimal if it's this, and varchar if it's that".   You have to decide on a single datatype for the column.

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Difference', table 'tempdb.dbo.#SweepActivityTransactions